# OS X editor (or IDE) that is really good for "node.js" development?

Tags: javascript, macos, node.js, pug, stylus

I'm an old Emacs user - I've used it for about 10years now. When I switched to Mac I started to use [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/), which is great in many ways.

But now most my development work involves Node.js/Express.js (with JavaScript, Jade and Stylus). Unfortunately, emacs has many shortcomings in this regard. Especially when working remotely, with [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/) and [MacFUSE](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/) mounts.

And I really want real code folding.

Is there any editor which is really good for this? Even better is there any IDE for Mac (at all)?

Thanks

Comment: @pst good edit, maybe that will stop the close votes

Comment: I use IntelliJ for most coding now, Sublime Text 2 is great but definitely not an IDE, and Emacs for everything else. IMO the question *is* off-topic, though; at best it belongs on programmers, although "recommendation engine" type stuff--meh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A cheaper and more node-specific alternative to IntelliJ IDEA is [Webstorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/), also made by Jetbrains.

It has a lot of node goodies like the ability to attach to the node debugger and allow you to step through your JS code. It also has good code folding, which you can invoke with `⌘^-` to fold and `⌘^+` to expand.

Comment: I have tried WebStorm for 2 days. And i am falling for it. It is an really good IDE. I use it with JavaScript, JADE and Stylus and it is perfect. It has really good documentation too. This will be my IDE of choise from now on. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you install the "key promoter" plugin, it works wonders helping you remember keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: @BadKnees, what are you doing for Stylus support in WebStorm? In order to get syntax highlighting and auto-completion, I've had to resort to adding curly braces and semicolons to my Stylus files and telling WebStorm to treat them as css.  I'd love to hear about a better alternative.

Comment: @DallanQuass sorry did not see this question. I got no solution. Its just text in my case

Answer (score 10):

[Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-2-beta) is the choice of many. Add [some packages](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/community) to it with the [package manager](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation). Jade, stylus packages available.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a real IDE that works well on Mac OS X I would recommend IntelliJ IDEA.  It has a JavaScript debugger and Node.js plugin.
If you are looking for something more lightweight than a full-blown IDE, take a look at Sublime Text 2.

Comment: Tried both. Dident like intelliJ, mostly because it's java. Very ugly. But sublime is very promising.

Comment: I'm not Mac OS look and feel fun or expert, but the new versions of IJ looks like they fit pretty well.

Comment: afaik Webstorm is IntelliJ modified for HTML/JS etc. (eg, not so Java centric). @MK. is that your understanding too or am I off base here?

Comment: @MikeGraf yeah, probably, but he was complaining about look and feel of a Java application running on OS X.

Answer (score 3):

You could try TextMate: http://macromates.com/
with the following bundles for

NodeJs: https://github.com/drnic/javascript-node.tmbundle

and for Jade: https://github.com/miksago/jade-tmbundle

For stylus you have to compile the bundle (haven't tried it yet): https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus/blob/master/docs/textmate.md

There is also Cloud9 ide https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9, its actually a webapp, but its open source and can be installed locally (it still runs in the browser, but locally), I really like the debugging features

Answer (score 0):

http://www.aptana.com/ is great, it has most of the eclipse features...